# Changing image when div is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm looking all day for solution. I try to make something like these:

sigma-topline2012.com/en-us/topline-2012/bc-5-12/overview.html#highlight

As you can see, when we move the mouse on description on right, then image is changing. Could anybody can help me with these? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, you should explain what you have tried. You can start with the jQuery [hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) function.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

http://jsfiddle.net/eah9bgkm/

```
<img id="image" src="http://placekitten.com/g/130/130" />

<ul>
    <li data-link="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">Cat 1</li>
    <li data-link="http://placekitten.com/g/151/151">Cat 2</li>
    <li data-link="http://placekitten.com/g/152/152">Cat 3</li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var img = $('#image');
    $('li').hover(function(){
        img.attr('src', $(this).data('link'));
    });    
});
```

Just add a css class to fadein/out

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="definition1">Definition 1</div>
<div id="definition2">Definition 2</div>
<img id="imageWrapper" src="image1.png" />
```

Javacript:

```
$("#definition1").hover(function(){
    $('#imageWrapper').attr("src", function(index, attr){
        return attr.replace("image1.png", "image2.png");
    });
}, function(){
    $('#imageWrapper').attr("src", function(index, attr){
        return attr.replace("image2.png", "image1.png");
    });
});
```